# Django sitemap various links for same model

Tags: django, sitemap, django-sitemaps

I created sitemap for my website in Django as below

**sitemap**

```
class MyModelSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return datetime.datetime.today()
```

**urls.py**

```
sitemaps = {
    'mymodel': MyModelSitemap,
    }
```

`get_absolute_link()` is also implemented for `MyModel`

The problem there are many other URLs that uses `MyModel` so it's not possible to have only one `absolute_link` for it.

I need to provide many other URLs to sitemap depending on different queries of `MyModel`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to create additional sitemaps:

```
class MyModelAdditionalLinkSitemap(MyModelSitemap):
    def location(self, obj):
        return obj.get_additional_link()
```

urls.py

```
sitemaps = {
    'mymodel': MyModelSitemap,
    'mymodel2': MyModelAdditionalLinkSitemap
}
```

**Added:**

I you want to use just one `Sitemap` class, try something like:

```
import itertools

class MyModelSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        product = itertools.product(MyModel.objects.all(), xrange(2))
        return list(product)

    def location(self, obj):
        if (obj[1] == 1):
            return obj[0].get_additional_link()
        return obj[0].get_absolute_link()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return datetime.datetime.today()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fine. Is there anyway to do it under only "mymodel" sitemap? Basically I want "mymodel": MyModelSitemap + MyModelAdditionalLinkSitemap

Comment: There is no difference in the resulting XML whether you build it with one or several ``Sitemap`` classes (unless you use sections). The only drawback I see is an extra DB requests. I've updated the answer with a single class though.